What can I do if I can't hear pitches?
I've been studying Japanese for four years and only recently became aware of pitch accents. I actually picked Japanese over Chinese because I cannot detect pitch changes, but now people are saying that without correct pitch I will never be understood.
To be honest, this is incredibly discouraging that I have wasted years of my life studying a language I can never speak. I've tried hundreds of paired pitches on kotu.io and I just can't hear the difference. I have watched a variety of different videos and, while they explain what it is, I just can't hear any difference between the different pitches.

Even the people who put the most emphasis on studying pitch rarely exaggerate that much. Do you have an example of someone saying that? If you just mean other learners like yourself, just rely on what trusted sources say.

Not a small number of native speakers are like that (崩壊アクセント, 無アクセント). Singers may ignore the word-level pitch patterns in preference of what the music requires.

As a Chinese speaker, even foreigners with horrible pitch in Chinese can be understood with some effort. Japanese does have some pitch but there are plenty of foreign speakers who completely ignore pitch and have pretty understandable speech.

FWIW, there's a popular Japanese text-to-speech program that speaks in mostly flat tone (bouyomi-chan), and many Japanese natives understand it.

"...without correct pitch I will never be understood." This is simply not true. Being understood is a continuum, from basic just-about-communication of simple things to being able to discuss some technical subject with fluency. The more natural your pronunciation, obviously the easier communication is. But the specific issue of pitch tones is far more nuanced than what people are telling you. Pitch accent varies hugely across Japan: in particular the Tohoku region has shiri-agari, the pitch rising at the end. Sitting between Tohoku and Tokyo is Tochigi-ken, said to be one of three prefectures in which there is no pitch accent. I happen to live there, and I would consider myself functionally fluent, but I cannot answer any of the "pitch accent" questions here or elsewhere. Moreover, if I try asking native speakers around me, they usually become vague and evasive, and seem to have no clear idea of what the answer should be either. Yet everyone communicates normally.
It is almost impossible to gain a native speaker accent after childhood; you can no doubt think of famous people who have very distinct accents, particularly ones English speakers are familiar with, like French or German (or "British" for American speakers), but of course these people are communicating successfully. Again, many native Japanese speakers who are fluent in English cannot actually distinguish l and r with accuracy - give them a "rump-lump-ramp-lamp" quiz, and they score 25%. Many Korean speakers of Japanese have never mastered voiced-unvoiced opposition, yet they are heard as having a Korean accent, not as being incomprehensible.
So I think your concern is hugely exaggerated. Concentrate on mimicing what you hear, and good luck!

First off, echoing all the other replies: you're making a mountain out of a molehill. I don't know how you managed to get the impression that pitch accent is absolutely crucial for being understood in Japanese, but that's simply not true. Many, many people are living proof of this — people who don't have a good grip on pitch accent, yet are great speakers who can communicate perfectly well — to say nothing of native speakers' ability to understand different dialects (with majorly different pitch accent) from their own. Speaking from a purely practical communication perspective, vast majority of the time, you can more than get by without it.

That said, if you nevertheless still want to learn to hear standard pitch (for whatever reason; perhaps personal achievement/satisfaction), then you could try booking a tutor to get corrections on your own spoken pitch. Try maybe 10 hours of this and see whether there's any progress. In general, explicit real-time instruction and demonstration might be what you need to orient your senses here.
If you want to hold off on spending money on this just yet, then I'll second Jimmie Zhao's suggestion to start with basic musical ear training first (train your ability to tell how two notes compare in terms of height in pitch). Try the first two exercises here, and then move onto the second one here. Report back once you can do well on these.
Finally, if you haven't done this already, try unchecking every box on kotu.io apart from atamadaka and heiban, and focusing on learning to differentiate just those two. Seconding Jimmie again, when you choose wrong, it's important to compare the audio for both options. Keep in mind, atamadaka is supposed to immediately drop from the 1st mora to the 2nd in a noticeable way; heiban is supposed to not do that (the exact specifics of how the pitch might go vary — sometimes heiban will start high and go low too, but the drop should be smaller and smoother/more gradual than atamadaka). Even if you can't discern pitch height or direction, try nonetheless getting a "feel" for the difference between how the two patterns sound through constant back-and-forth comparison! Even if you can't specifically tell a rise from a fall in pitch for the life of you, you can probably still identify "shapes" of pitch to some extent, for some purposes — for instance in telling statements vs. questions apart (e.g. you can probably tell the difference in delivery between "He's going to France." and "He's going to France?" — which is a matter of intonation, aka the variation of pitch throughout each sentence — though you might not recognise the rises as rises, or the falls as falls).
If none of these yield any results, then I'll stress once again: don't sweat it. You'll be just fine either way. Forget about this and go have fun learning and using the language.

When you do questions on kotu.io do and play the audio of both answers do you hear a difference at all or do both samples sound exactly the same?
Go to a random music pitch trainer website and do the test for identifying which pitch is lower or higher. So given two piano audio samples can you tell which one is higher pitcher or does it literally sound the same to you?
If you can the you probably aren't incapable of hearing pitch your ears are just probably not looking for the right thing. Also could you give us what you score in kotu.io just out of curiosity?

・As others have already mentioned, the pitch accent is fluid among dialects, and even there exist dialect that does not utilize pitch as accent (i.e. to distinguish words). So, it is not practically important to pronounce words with the correct pitch. Context and vocabulary are far more important.
・To hear and to pronounce the difference in pitch is two different skills. Even if you do not perceive any difference when you hear the recordings, you may be able to produce such difference.
